# How to declare global variable for google closure compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

```
(function(){ window.myGlobal=42})();
console.error(myGlobal);
```

java -jar compiler.jar --jscomp_warning undefinedVars

WARNING - variable myGlobal is undeclared

Comment: Did you try console.error(window.myGlobal)??

Comment: Of course, it works, but the goal is to not have to prefix with "window."

Comment: Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations)

Comment: @Rohan If you refer to this :

If you need to refer to a variable as a property of the global object, always refer to it that way:

`window.foo = {}`
`window.foo;`

My point is the opposite : how to always refer to the global variable as myGlobal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rohan points out in the comments, the Closure compiler thinks of `window.myGlobal` and `myGlobal` as different things, even though you and I know they are actually the same. If you need to define it inside a function, you could do something like

```
var myGlobal;
(function() { myGlobal = 42; })();
console.log(myGlobal);
```

or, use `window` in all cases:

```
window.myGlobal = null;
(function() { window.myGlobal = 42; })();
console.log(window.myGlobal);
```

Comment: Your first solution is the most elegant one, Thank you for this idea !

Comment: Yes, thanks for the idea, although that is still not a way to declare a variable as global (for example, declared in another JS file the closure-compiler is not given for compilation).